# How to solve 'a÷b(c+d)'?

Tags: arithmetic

How to solve $a÷b(c+d)$?

For example, $2÷4(8+16)$.

Is it $($$\frac{2}{4}$$)(8+16)$ = $\frac{1}{2}$(8+16) = $\frac{1}{2}$(24) = 12?

or $\frac{2}{4(8+16)}$ = $\frac{2}{4*24}$ = $\frac{2}{96}$ = $\frac{1}{48}$?

Which one is the right one?

Comment: What is there to solve in your question? You have no equation.

Comment: The first one: $\frac{2}{4}(8+16)=\frac{1}{2}24=12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never forget your order of operations:

**P**arentheses
**E**xponentiation
**M**ultiplication and **D**ivision
**A**ddition and **S**ubtraction

For the "and" lines: these operations have the same level of priority. Now you go **left to right**.

For example: $35 \cdot 2 / 7 \cdot 6 = 70 / 7 \cdot 6 = 10 \cdot 6 = 60$

Comment: Why is it not  $$\frac{35 * 2 * 6}{7}$$?

Comment: Is this wrong?: $$\frac{70}{7}*6=10*6=60$$

Comment: You wrote $35⋅2/7⋅6=70/7⋅6=10/6$. Is it the right answer or a just mistake?

Comment: @User sorry, that was a mistake. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that a better solution is to ask the person who wrote this expression down to re-write it in a more clear manner.

The purpose of notation (and implicitly, the order of operations rules people talk about) is not to torture and confuse students, but to communicate information successfully from one person to another. Expressions like
$$
a \div b (c + d)
$$
are *technically* unambiguous if we have all agreed on the order of operations beforehand. However, they aren't very clear (and hence are *in practice* ambiguous) and so a better solution is to either add more brackets before you write it down, or to write it as either
$$
\frac{a}{b(c + d)}
$$
or
$$
\frac{a}{b}(c + d)
$$
depending on which of those two is actually meant.

Written mathematics shouldn't be a guessing game for the reader. If they don't know what you meant due to potentially unclear notation, this isn't their fault.

Comment: The exercise could be to use order of operations, so asking for clarification defeats the purpose. That might not be the case, but we do welcome questions of _all_ levels.

Comment: Fair! But I do see these things being passed around often with many, many people arguing over the "right" answer, so just in case it is that, I felt I should add this perspective in.

Comment: I think it's also important to note that the order of operations is not something handed down from on high in the form of stone tablets. They are a convention to communicate information unambiguously, and no more.

Answer (score 0):

They way it is written, assuming the usual [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), it should be
$$2/4(8+16) = 2/4(24) = .5(24) = 12$$ since you do division **OR** multiplication from left to right, after parentheses and exponents.

Comment: What does this mean?: $.5(24)$

Comment: @장은수 $.5(24) = .5\times 24 = \frac{1}{2}\times 24 = 12$